# Crystal report export functionality not working with iframe

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have shown the crystal report in the ifrmae.
But I am unable to export to any format like pdf/excel or any.

Comment: Is there any error shown in your browser console?

Comment: Firstly Thanks for your comment.
Here is no any error message shown to me also I have checked in the console also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you got!

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ..fill the report..
}
```

but don't forget to close it (this will avoid report counter to reach the limit!)

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 reportDocument.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the issue,
When you want to export the report in the any format you need to be call your code/function of that report filler in the Pageinit like-
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// Your code or function call
}
Then it's definitely works!!!
Regards,
Ram.